# Making regex replacement optional

Tags: java, regex

So I have a regular expression to search for and be replaced by another regular expression in java. I am using grouping and was wondering if there was a way to make a group in the replacement optional.
For example, here is the regex i am searching for:

```
^(\d*).(\d)(\d?)$
```

could i do something like this for the replacement if the third group doesn't exist:

```
$1$2$3?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Do you want the dot to match an actual decimal dot? In that case, you'd need `\.` instead of `.` in your regex. Otherwise, that regex would also match `123x45`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't, but you don't need to do this, either.

If the third group doesn't match, `$3` will be the empty string, so it won't change the result of the replace operation.

Comment: Thank you. It was giving me an error because I didn't have a ? on the second grouping.